# Jquery: select all underneath class ".last" do multiple options to each element

Tags: jquery, class, select

I just simply want to select each element after the class ".last".

+++ SELECT EVERYTHING UNDERNEATH CLASS +++

--> All lines of html elements here.

Likewise...

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="option"></div>
    <div class="option"></div>
    <div class="option"></div>
    <div class="last"></div>
    <div class="option"></div>
    <div class="option">
    <img src="a.jpg"/>
    <table>
       <td><tr>1</tr></td>
       <td><tr>2</tr></td>
    </table>
    </div>
    <div class="option"></div>
</body>
```

Jquery:

```
$('*').nextAll(".last").each(function (i) {

       $(this).css('background-color','red');
       function({...
              this.text(..);
              etc...
       });

});
```

What I want to acomplish:

```
<body>
    <div class="option"></div>
    <div class="option"></div>
    <div class="option"></div>
    <div class="last"></div>
    <div class="option" style="background-color:red;"></div>
    <div class="option" style="background-color:red;">
         <img style="background-color:red;" src="a.jpg"/>
             <table style="background-color:red;">
                  <td style="background-color:red;">
                     <tr style="background-color:red;">abc</tr>
                  </td>
                  <td style="background-color:red;">
                     <tr style="background-color:red;">abc</tr>
                  </td>
             </table>
    </div>
    <div class="option" style="background-color:red;"></div>
</body>
```

EDIT:

NEED A FUNCTION IN IT HOW()?
I need to select ALL elements below .last class and apply multiple options to it.

Comment: Can you please format your question properly and not yell randomly? This is a professional community. Thanks.

Comment: I don't even know if this is possible to do. sorry ok... But to me it makes sense...

Comment: FYI: the correct markup would be: `<tr><td>content</td></tr>`

Comment: Its not the html thats important sry forgot to mention that...

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `each` as jQuery will be able to apply your CSS rule to all of your elements.

```en
$('.last').nextAll().each(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    // more code...
});
```

As a side note. You have errors in your HTML. (broken code), I assume this is just a typo for the examples, but you may want to verify.

Comment: This will only apply to siblings of `.last`. In this case, it shouldn't matter as the colour should be inherited, but it's not exactly what the OP is looking for as they seem to want to select all descendants of all the following siblings too.

Comment: @KimmyC, Haha, no... missing comma. Meant to say *I* edited my post.

Comment: $('.last').nextAll().each(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    $(this).css('margin-left', '10px');
    // more code...
});​
did try that did not work with two commands...? But it should? I dont know

Comment: What do you mean by "did not work with two commands"? Notice that `each(function() { ... all code here ... });` is a function, which means you can run any code against all matched elements which `each` is looping through.

Answer (score 1):

you dont need javascript for that, this css-rule works for you:

```
​.last ~ *{
     background-color:red;        
}​
```

edit: compat down to IE7

[here's the according fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ktKJn/) for you.

Comment: this is no problem, it's nice valid css and even IE7 gets it.

Comment: @KimmyC It also makes it cleaner, because you don't mess up your markup with nasty inline styles.